# Does Zurb Foundation 5 have a token field?

Tags: zurb-foundation, jquery-tokeninput, bootstrap-tokenfield

I'm looking for a token field (or token input) to use with Foundation 5 project. I did not find any on their website.

Bootstrap has one for e.g.: http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/

and jQuery too: http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

I there a plugin for foundation somewhere?